# Consolidate and invoice against multiple purchase orders. x++ ax 2012

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, purchase-order

I have an integration project where I need to post purchase orders in x++.  I already have it working posting invoices against a purchase order by looking up the PO. populating the vendInvoiceInfoTable, the vendInvoiceInfoSubTable, vendInvoiceInfoLine and vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.

Then when I want to post I call this code when complete and it posts just fine.

```
            purchFormLetterInvoice = PurchFormLetter_Invoice::newFromSavedInvoice(vendInvoiceInfoTable);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.showQueryForm(false);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.specQty(PurchUpdate::PackingSlip);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.update(vendInvoiceInfoTable, vendInvoiceInfoTable.Num, systemdateget());
```

The issue now is that I want to add multiple purchase orders to the invoice.  I'm able to add the lines to the vendorinvoice by code and when I go look on the front end it shows up as "multiple" for purchase order and product receipts on the front end.  I also add the reference table by adding the below code.  I basically add this snippet twice if I have 2 Purchase orders , i just replace the OriginPurchID.

```
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.clear();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.initValue();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.defaultRow();

           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.OrigPurchId = "PO-XXX";
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.TableRefId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.TableRefId;
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.PurchName = purchTable.PurchName;
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.insert();
```

The issue is when I call the code below to post, it hits an error during the posting code which is below here.

```
 if (vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.SourceAccountingEvent != localAccountingEvent.RecId)
    {
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.ErrorInvalidDistribution = NoYes::Yes;
        throw error("@SYS326999");
    }
```

It then causes this error:  The purchase order or product receipt was corrected after the vendor invoice was created. All accounting distributions must be re-created to reflect any changes to the purchase order's or product receipt's accounting distributions.

Even if I force to enter the next "event ID" to vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.SourceAccountingEvent it fails after words in another method. I'm running out of things to try.  But I believe some linking or maybe a different way to post might be the solution but i'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Also the weird thing is when If i run the code without posting and just stage it in AX. I go to the PO and try to post.. it gives me the same error.. but if I try it again the 2nd time.. it actually posts and gets by that error which is weird.

Here is the majority of the code while removing private info..

```
           purchTable = purchTable::find(poNum);

    vendInvoiceInfoTable.clear();
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.initValue();

        vendInvoiceInfoTable.initFromPurchTable(purchTable);

        vendInvoiceInfoTable.OrderAccount= purchtable.OrderAccount;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.InvoiceAccount= purchTable.InvoiceAccount;


        vendInvoiceInfoTable.Approved = NoYes::Yes;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.DocumentOrigin  = DocumentOrigin::Manual;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.CurrencyCode = purchTable.CurrencyCode;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.DocumentDate=invoiceDate;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.Description=invoiceHeader.get_Description();
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.DeliveryName = purchTable.DeliveryName;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.PurchName = purchTable.PurchName;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.BatchAdministration = NoYes::Yes;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.ParmJobStatus = ParmJobStatus::Waiting;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.FixedDueDate = purchTable.FixedDueDate;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.LastMatchVariance = LastMatchVarianceOptions::OK;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.TransDate = systemDateGet();
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.VendInvoiceSaveStatus = VendInvoiceSaveStatus::Pending;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.Num=InvoiceNum;
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.InventSiteId=purchtable.InventSiteId;



        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,RemittanceLocation),null,purchTable);
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,FixedDueDate),null,purchTable);
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,ExchRate),null,purchTable);
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,TransDate),null,purchTable);
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,PaymMode),null,purchTable);
        vendInvoiceInfoTable.defaultField(fieldNum(VendInvoiceInfoTable,PaymSpec),null,purchTable);

         vendInvoiceInfoTable.insert();

     if(vendInvoiceInfoTable)
          {


           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.clear();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.initValue();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.defaultRow();

           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.ParmId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.ParmId;
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.OrigPurchId = "po-number1";
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.TableRefId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.TableRefId;
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.PurchName = purchTable.PurchName;
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.insert();



           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.clear();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.initValue();
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.defaultRow();

           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.ParmId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.ParmId;

           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.OrigPurchId = "po-number2";
           vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.TableRefId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.TableRefId;
          vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.PurchName = purchTable.PurchName;
            vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.insert();

         //vendInvoiceInfoTable.selectForUpdate(true);
       // vendInvoiceInfoTable.SourceDocumentHeader = 0;
       // vendInvoiceInfoTable.SourceDocumentLine = 0;
       // vendInvoiceInfoTable.doUpdate();
          //  sourceDocumentProcessorFacade::submitSourceDocumentImplementation(vendInvoiceInfoTable,1);

 }

  //next part will loop through and create all the lines

   while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.clear();
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.initValue();
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.initFromPurchLine(purchLine);

    vendInvoiceInfoLine.DeliveryName = vendInvoiceInfoTable.DeliveryName;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.ParmId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.ParmId;

    vendInvoiceInfoLine.TableRefId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.TableRefId;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.currencyCode = vendInvoiceInfoTable.CurrencyCode;

    vendInvoiceInfoLine.InvoiceAccount = vendInvoiceInfoTable.InvoiceAccount;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.InventDimId = purchLine.InventDimId;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.OrderAccount  = vendInvoiceInfoTable.OrderAccount;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.InventTransId = purchLine.InventTransId;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.PurchPrice=purchLine.PurchPrice;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.InventNow = calculatedQty;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.ReceiveNow = calculatedQty;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.RemainBefore = calculatedQty;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.RemainBeforeInvent = calculatedQty;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.DefaultDimension = purchLine.DefaultDimension;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.LineAmount = amt;
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.insert();


   while select * from vendPackingSlipTrans
                                                         where vendPackingSlipTrans.OrigPurchid==purchLine.PurchId
                                                            && vendPackingSlipTrans.InventTransId==purchLine.InventTransId
                                                {
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.clear();
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.initValue();
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.defaultRow();
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.ParmId = vendInvoiceInfoTable.ParmId;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.LineRefRecId = vendInvoiceInfoLine.RecId;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.ReceiveNow = vendPackingSlipTrans.Qty;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.InventNow = vendPackingSlipTrans.Qty;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.JournalRefRecId = vendPackingSlipTrans.RecId;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.JournalRefTableId = vendPackingSlipTrans.TableId;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.DocumentId = vendPackingSlipTrans.PackingSlipId;
                                                vendInvoiceInfoSubLine.insert();



                                                }

}

            purchFormLetterInvoice = PurchFormLetter_Invoice::newFromSavedInvoice(vendInvoiceInfoTable);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.showQueryForm(false);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.specQty(PurchUpdate::PackingSlip);
            purchFormLetterInvoice.update(vendInvoiceInfoTable, vendInvoiceInfoTable.Num, systemdateget());
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.SourceAccountingEvent`? Is it `0`?

You haven't provided enough of your posting code, but when I see `SourceAccountingEvent` I immediately think that you might not be using the source document framework when you need to.

You may need to use a line like the following:

> `SourceDocumentProcessorFacade::submitSourceDocumentLineImplementation(...);`

There used to be a great blog about the *Source Document Framework*, but disappeared. You can still find it on the wayback machine here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150323025403/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ax_gfm_framework_team_blog/archive/2012/04/26/extending-the-source-document-framework.aspx

If your issue is not related to the *Source Document Framework*, this answer won't help much.

Comment: Yes its 0 for the subtable of the additional PO when i debug. The first subtable has a valid source accounting event but the 2nd one is 0 and fails.  Not sure exactly what that is.

Comment: I've been looking at the SourceDocumentProcessorFacade::submitSourceDocumentLineImplementation(vendInvoiceInfoLine, 1);
Nothing seems to work and i'm still getting the same error, not sure exactly what I did to fix.

Comment: @Sirus - Place a breakpoint there (you may need to turn `CIL` off), and post invoice(s) manually. I don't have all of your code, so I don't have a full picture, but I'm thinking your issue is related to that framework. You may need the packing slip, subtable, etc, I'm not sure without really debugging. If you can post all of your code in a job-style that's more repeatable, it'd be easier to figure out. There should be all sorts of invoice posting code online though.

Comment: I edited my initial post with more code... there isn't alot of code online that actually works for consolidating multiple POS on an invoice

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this method? You're directly populating the underlying tables, then trying to shove them through the invoice process, which means you have to get **everything** correct for successful posting. Have you tried the `TmpFrmVirtual` method? https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/87761/regarding-multiple-po-invoice-through-x.

Comment: Actually this little piece of code fixed it all.

        localAccountingEvent = AccountingEvent::getLastEvent(PurchTable::find(vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.OrigPurchId).SourceDocumentHeader);
                vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.SourceAccountingEvent = localAccountingEvent.RecId;
                  vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.update();

This populated soureaccounting event for my 2nd subtable which for some reason was never hitting this method in the base code to get populated.

Comment: Also I have tried lots of different methods to do POs. and this was the only method for our environment and requirements that worked. I've also seen that article before.. didn't work for me

Comment: You should **really** verify that's functioning correctly, even if it appears to work. That's just getting the last accounting event associated with the PO, and I'm saying you may need to submit a new accounting event to use with your posting. I *think* it's an atomic process, where it gets one during your posting, but I can't remember. You should do a manual posting w/multiple PO's, check your final `SourceDocument*` fields on `VendInvoice[Jour/Trans]` and see if they match what the `getLastEvent(...)` would have returned. Check at various points in the posting too.

Comment: If it's wrong, it's possible it would go unnoticed for a long time until some sort of accounting audit, then I think when viewing the subledger journal or accounting distributions, things wouldn't line up and then you might realize that you've been doing tons of postings and just dumping bad links into that field...or it could be working perfectly? I'd just make sure you've got that bit right.

Comment: Yes I will do alot more testing.. the thing i don't understand is, when debugging there is a method called initSubTableSourceAccountingEventNew() that takes the vendInvoiceInfoSubTable.  This sets the first subtable, but the second subtable with the other PO number never calls this method, so it doesn't get set and therefore fails. Theres a disconnect there....

Comment: If you're talking about `\C\PurchFormletterParmDataInvoice\initSubTableSourceAccountingEvent()` it's decorated with `[SysObsoleteAttribute('This method is no longer used.', true)]`

Comment: No, i'm talking about that name but with "New" on the end.

Comment: Ah, gotta love AX method sorting. For the future, providing the class name + method name is more helpful. From just looking at the code, I'd guess in `\C\PurchFormletterParmDataInvoice\chooseLinesFromPurchSelectLinesManager #157` is looking for distinct per the comment `// create VendInvoiceInfoSubTable row for each distinct OrigPurchId`, and that's why it's not calling multiple? It sounds like you have it working and/or testing though, so hopefully all is good.

Comment: What I found during my posting code, it calls an updateParmID method which then calls PurchFormletterParmDataInvoice::initSubTableSourceAccountingEventNew only if this "IsAccountingEventchanged" is false. the first one is always false.  Then as it loops through all the vendInvoiceInfoSubTables , after it updates the first one, it  returns true back, therefore skipping any additional subtables to update its Accounting Event.. weird..

Comment: My code also doesn't call \PurchFormletterParmDataInvoice\chooseLinesFromPurchSelectLinesManager fyi